# How to use the layout() function in plotly to set axes titles R

Tags: r, plotly

I am somewhat new to R and plotly. I have a scatter plot that I want to edit the axes titles. I have tried using the pipe operator %>% with layout() to edit the axes titles but I am getting the following error. Everywhere I have looked shows that my code should work but I keep getting the same error.

```
scatter <- plot_ly(
  data = clean,
  x = ~MilesToCampus,
  y = ~PriceMonth,
  size = ~Capacity,
  text = ~paste("Apartment: ", Apartment, 
                "\n", 
                "Price: $", PriceMonth, 
                "\n",
                "Distance to Campus: ", MilesToCampus,
                "\n",
                "Capacity: ", Capacity) %>% 
    layout(title = "Does Distance to Campus Affect Housing Cost?",
           xaxis = list(title = "Distance to Campus (miles)"),
           yaxis = list(title = "Price (USD)")))
scatter
```

Error in UseMethod("layout") :
no applicable method for 'layout' applied to an object of class "character"

Below is a picture of the data I am using.

[Here is a picture of the output of dput(head(clean))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgzD9.png)

Comment: Can you provide your data in a reproducible format using `dput` ? Edit your post to include output of `dput(head(clean, 10))`.

Comment: @RonakShah I added the data I am using to my question.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Images are not helpful. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a parenthesis-matching error... try the following (moving a parenthesis from the end of `layout` to the end of `paste`:

```r
scatter <- plot_ly(
  data = clean,
  x = ~MilesToCampus,
  y = ~PriceMonth,
  size = ~Capacity,
  text = ~paste("Apartment: ", Apartment, 
                "\n", 
                "Price: $", PriceMonth, 
                "\n",
                "Distance to Campus: ", MilesToCampus,
                "\n",
                "Capacity: ", Capacity)) %>% 
    layout(title = "Does Distance to Campus Affect Housing Cost?",
           xaxis = list(title = "Distance to Campus (miles)"),
           yaxis = list(title = "Price (USD)"))
scatter
```